# Dojo: Correct way to 'Hitch' scope of deferred types

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope, dojo

I am experiencing difficulty passing scope through the following Dojo widget's asynchronous structure:

```
function callDef(){
//This function has the scope I need
        var deferred = new Deferred();
//try to hitch 'this' to function2
    DojoBaseLang.hitch(this,deferred.resolve(function2(1)));
    deferred.then(DojoBaseLang.hitch(this, function(callback) {
        callback.then(
            function (desiredResult) {
                //How to hitch callDef initial scope to function3?
                function3(desiredResult);
            },
            function (err) {
                // Do something when the process errors out
                console.log(err);
           })
           }),
    function (err) {
        // Do something when the process errors out
        console.log(err);
    }
);
function function2(variable){
//callDef scope not passed by hitch :(
    var dataStucture;
    //deferredFunction is a function which returns type Deferred
     return deferredFunction(hierarchyTableQuery, function(dataSet){
         //some iterative maniupulations will be performed on dataStructure here
         dataStructure = dataSet;

     }).then(function (){
         return dataStructure;
     });
}

function function3(variable){
    //need a way to also have scope in this method
    //doing other stuff
}
```

As you can see, callDef first calls into function2, returns a deferred, finishes execution and then passes the result from function2's `dataStructure` object into function3. This all works fine in terms of Deferred/Async behavior, the problem is that the `dojo/_base/lang.hitch` function being called is not passing the scope from function to function as it usually does, in this case from `callDef` to `function2`. I would also like to pass the same scope into `function3`. My require statement is correct, and I have other non-async `.hitch` calls which are successful in the same widget/file.

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: OMG. It's called "context" or "receiver", not *scope*, looks like the Dojo docs need to be fixed. And really if you write code in 2016, you should use [the `bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) not some `hitch` function. Or just use arrow functions straight away.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can you expand what you are implying with arrow functions. It appears, according to [Arrow function guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) : *Arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target*

Comment: Yes, exactly those. You might also want to have a look at our canonical question on the subject: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
…
deferred.resolve(DojoBaseLang.hitch(this,function2));
deferred.then(DojoBaseLang.hitch(this, function(callback) {
    callback(1).then(
        DojoBaseLang.hitch(this,function3),
        function (err) {
… // rest of the code
```

Comment: this worked, only when I used the `.hitch` call inline with the first `.resolve` call, the JS interpreter complained that `callback.then() is not a function` 
Otherwise, works exactly as needed

Comment: Notice that I changed `callback.then` to `callback(1).then`. Your original code doesn't really make a lot of sense (creating deferreds that are immidiately fulfilled with a function?), this was my best guess. Maybe you should present your whole code at [codereview.SE]